# Two different .NET applications can't access the db4o file

Tags: c#, .net, db4o

I have just downloaded and and am using db40 7.9 and am testing it on two different .NET 3.5 applications using the supplied tutorial.

When I access the same database (c:\pilot.db4o) file using these two applications, one after the other, each one is reflecting only the changes made by that application, even if those changes were made during the previous run.

Why is each Application not seeing changes the other application made to the database file?

Comment: I'd need more info to try and help you with this - perhaps you could post a sample recreating your problem to the db4o forums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the object model defined in each application? Do you have a (a) third assembly that defines this object model or (b) you duplicated it in each app?

Scenario **B** will not work since db4o needs to remember the assembly name.

PS: I know this is a late answer but I think the information is useful for others.

Adriano

Answer (score 0):

In such a case be sure you commited the results and close the db, so that the next application can access the file and see the commited results.

But in case you need to access from multiple 'clients' you should try using client / server mode!

> even if those changes were made during the previous run.

What do you mean with this?